# How can take *x as variable in python?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a  symbolic sequence like x1,x2,...,x20 (without brackets). Can I take this sequence as variables in python? in other word `y=x1,x2,x3,...,x20` ?
At fist my list was `x=[x1,x2,...,x20]` and with command `*x` I converted it to sequence`x1,x2,...,x20` and now for continuing my program I need to take this sequence as variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Please add more information about what you're trying to do. *x on an array doesn't make any sense in Python

Comment: make it clearer that you are working with `sympy`.  But also don't confuse the symbols and python variables that can reference them.  Study the sympy examples with care

Comment: Please make it clear, what x1, x2, ... are. Do you have strings? Are these variables? If yes, how are they defined?

Comment: I want to take a variable like y that equal to symbolic  sequence x1,x2,...,x20

Comment: I have not string @Matthias, x1,x2,... are symbolic variables

Comment: what are you going to do with that sequence?

Comment: I need them for optimization

Comment: be more specific about the 'optimization'.  What `sympy` code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you used `*x` to convert the sequence to variables (and you can only do `*x` in a function call or function signature like:

```py
def f(x1,x2):
    print(x1, x2)
x = var('x1 x2')
>>> f(*x)
(x1, x2)
```

it seems like you mean that "once in the function, can I get the list of variables again?"
The answer is "yes" -- the same way that you made them in the first place:

```py
def f(x1, x2):
    y = x1, x2
    print(y)
>>> f(*x)
(x1, x2)
```

But maybe you mean "without having to retype the list?" The solution is to pass them as a tuple instead of unpacking them with the "*" operator:

```py
def f(y):
    print(y)
>>> f(x)  # passing as tuple, not unpacking
(x1, x2)
```

(It is always better to add a little code so there is less guessing what you mean.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can indeed treat a sequence of symbols as separate variables in Python. Your initial approach of having a list x = [x1, x2, ..., x20] and then unpacking it using the * operator is correct to create a sequence.
Suppose your initial list is:
x = [value1, value2, ..., value20]
You can unpack this list directly into variables using tuple unpacking:
x1, x2, x3, ..., x20 = x
Now, x1, x2, x3, ..., x20 are independent variables with the corresponding values from the original list.
If you want to continue working with these variables as a sequence, you can simply reference them in a tuple or list again:
y = x1, x2, x3, ..., x20  # This creates a tuple